# IPsec Connection Ports

Tags: vpn, ipsec

i configured a VPN server with IPsec to surfe secure at public networks. At generally it works. Now i would like to access my vpn server from my campus. Here i can't get any connection.

I know, that the campus administrator block all ports under 1024 except http and https.
I also know, that IPsec use UDP 500 and 4500.

1. Do you think it is enough to change the port UDP 500 to a higher port? Are there other ports important for IPsec under 1024?
2. Does IPsec work with TCP instead UDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. IPsec has 2 phases, the first phase involves IKE(aka ISAKMP) protocol which uses udp port 500.Port 4500 is only used when dealing with nat traversal.
2. The standard defines the phase 1 using udp protocol, and the software is implemented in the same manner.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, i can only change the port 500 higher and hope that they will not block UDP or switch to for example openvpn. Greetz.

Comment: yes,i believe so.